# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have this section of php code:

```
$dcs = mysql_query("SELECT `locations.l_name`, `locations.location_id`
                    FROM `locations`, `cabinet`
                    WHERE `locations.location_id` = `cabinet.datacentre_id`
                    GROUP BY `locations.location_id`
                    ORDER BY `locations.l_name`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dcs)) {
echo '<option value="' .$row['location_id']. '">' .htmlspecialchars($row['l_name']). '</option>';                               }
```

But when I run it I get this error:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with the database, not the code.. Any ideas what the issue could be? Or what I need to look out for?

Comment: just echo the sql query you are trying to execute

Comment: check if the query you are running is correct .. there might be some mistake due to which query is not being successfully executed ..... use mysql_error() or try running the query in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

your `SELECT` query is incorrect. You are wrapping the tablename and column name as one causing the server could not find the column name. they should be wrapped individually.

```
SELECT  `locations`.`l_name`, 
        `locations`.`location_id`
FROM    `locations`, `cabinet`
WHERE   `locations`.`location_id` = `cabinet`.`datacentre_id`
GROUP   BY `locations`.`location_id`
ORDER   BY `locations`.`l_name`
```

Since non of them are reserved keyowrds in mysql, `backticks` are optional.

```
SELECT  locations.l_name, 
        locations.location_id
FROM    locations, cabinet
WHERE   locations.location_id = cabinet.datacentre_id
GROUP   BY locations.location_id
ORDER   BY locations.l_name
```

One more thing, please use the newer syntax of joins.

```
SELECT  locations.l_name, 
        locations.location_id
FROM    locations 
        INNER JOIN cabinet 
            ON locations.location_id = cabinet.datacentre_id
GROUP   BY locations.location_id
ORDER   BY locations.l_name
```

Comment: @user1738017 try the last update query which uses `INNER JOIN` and without backtick

Comment: just did, still nothing :(

Comment: try running it directly in mysql or on phpmyadmin. the last query.

Comment: have you tried running the query already?

Comment: no, I don't have access to phpmyadmin..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26361/discussion-between-jw-and-user1738017)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me... although note of course that this PHP method is 'deprecated'!...

```
<?php

 include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');
 $query = "
 SELECT DISTINCT l.l_name
               , l.location_id
            FROM locations l
            JOIN cabinet c
              ON c.datacentre_id = l.location_id  
           ORDER 
              BY l.l_name;
              ";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
 echo '<option value="' .$row['location_id']. '">' .htmlspecialchars($row['l_name']). '</option>';
 }
 ?>
```